# How to hide the properties in TS interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with TS' interfaces.

I declared the interface `IAwaitable` with this code:

```
export interface IAwaitable {
    _tW: boolean; // _toWait
    _w(): void; // _waiting
}
```

and I implements it in the class `Formatter` with this code:

```
import { IAwaitable } from "../Interfaces/IAwaitable"
import { ColorOptions } from "../Utils/Globals/Utils"
import { GMap } from "../Utils/Globals/Collection"
import { Utils } from "../Utils/Globals/Utils"

export class Formatter implements IAwaitable {

    _tW: boolean = false;
    private chalk = import("chalk");
    private _opt: FormattingOptions[];
    private _chalkInstances: GMap<string, any> = new GMap<string, any>();

    public constructor(...options: FormattingOptions[]) {
        this._opt = options;
        this._pC();
    }

    private _pC(): void { // _prepareChalk
        this._tW = true;

        this.chalk.then((m) => {
            for(let i: number = 0; i < Utils.colorsName.length; i++) this._chalkInstances.add(Utils.colorsName[i], m.default.hex(Utils.colorsString[i]))
        });

        this._tW = false;
    }

    _w(): void { // _waiting
        while(this._tW);
    }
}

export interface FormattingOptions {
    string: string,
    color: keyof ColorOptions
}
```

and if I try to construct an `Formatter` object I can access to `_tW` and `_w`.

I tried to declare it as protected but it didn't work because TS said that they were declared protected in `Formatter` but not in `IAwaitable`.

If I try to declare them as protected in `IAwaitable` it gives me TS1070 error.

How can I hide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want them to be visible in the interface, don't put them in.  They can then be instance variables in the class implementation, marked private.

The interface describes what IS visible.  Within a class, you have the ability to have private/protected members which are not part of the published interface.